# Hi, i canot publish an array to ros from arduino ide

Tags: ros, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

enter code here

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <Wire.h>
    #define    LIDARLite_ADDRESS   0x62         
    #define    RegisterMeasure     0x00         
    #define    MeasureValue        0x04       
    #define    RegisterHighLowB    0x8f         
    #define USB_USBCON
    #include <LIDARLite.h>
    #include <I2C.h>
    #include <sensor_msgs/Range.h>
    #include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
     LIDARLite myLidarLite;
     ros::NodeHandle  nh;
     sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan;
     ros::Publisher pub_range( "lidar", &scan);
     float ranges[7];
      char frameid[] = "/my_frame";
     int lidarGetRange(void) 
     {
     int val = -1;
     Wire.beginTransmission((int)LIDARLite_ADDRESS); 
     Wire.write((int)RegisterMeasure); 
     Wire.write((int)MeasureValue);   
     Wire.endTransmission(); 
      delay(20); 
     Wire.beginTransmission((int)LIDARLite_ADDRESS);
     Wire.write((int)RegisterHighLowB); 
     Wire.endTransmission(); 
     delay(20); 
     Wire.requestFrom((int)LIDARLite_ADDRESS, 2);
     if(2 <= Wire.available()) 
     {
     val = Wire.read(); 
     val = val << 8; 
     val |= Wire.read();
      }
      return val;
      }
     void setup()
      {
     Serial.begin(57600);
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(pub_range);
    //delay(1000);
     myLidarLite.begin(0, true);
    myLidarLite.configure(0);
    scan.header.frame_id =  frameid;
    scan.angle_min= 0; 
     scan.angle_max= 3.14;
    scan.angle_increment =1; 
    scan.range_min = 0.03;  
    scan.range_max = 4000; 
          } 
     void loop()
      {
     for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
         {
      Serial.println(lidarGetRange());
      scan.ranges[i] =lidarGetRange();   
       pub_range.publish(&scan);
         }
        nh.spinOnce();
      }`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274454/hi,-i-canot-publish-an-array-to-ros-from-arduino-ide./) by [ARUN T S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32369/arun-t-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-29**:
We're all here to help so no need for the "plz help"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-29**:
Make sure you're not using the same serial port for ROS *and* for `Serial.println(..)`). That will not work.

Also: make sure you have a large enough buffer on the Arduino side (`LaserScan` msgs are big), and search ROS Answers for similar Q&As. There have been a few.

**Comment by [shubham](https://answers.ros.org/users/32428/shubham/) on 2017-10-29**:
make sure you are adding ros header at the top of the code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-29**:
So in general: @ARUN T S: in order for us to all stop *guessing* what migth be wrong here, please update your question to include the relevant (and required) information. See [wiki/Support](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29).

**Comment by [ARUN T S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32369/arun-t-s/) on 2017-10-31**:
i edited my question ,this is my full program, can u guys find out what is the error in my program?
am trying to create a map of surroundings with a lidar lite v3 using hector slam

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
I see a `Serial.println(lidarGetRange());` and use of ROS in the same program. Have you made sure that those two are not using the same serial port?

Also: please see the [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29): we cannot ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
.. help you because all you wrote was "I canot publish". Does that mean that everything appears to work, but there are no messages? Are you getting error messages printed on your console? Is `rosserial` complaining about desyncs? Etc.

**Comment by [ARUN T S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32369/arun-t-s/) on 2017-11-02**:
Getting error message when i tries to establish serial publication between arduino and ros

```
[ERROR] [1509616280.864411]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

When i remove for loop no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please **remove** the following line:

```
Serial.println(lidarGetRange());
```

You **cannot** use the serial port through `Serial` *and* use `rosserial` at the same time.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARUN T S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32369/arun-t-s/) on 2017-11-03**:
That's it, Thank you  gvhoorn , and i also have to remove delay

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
Please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks.

**Comment by [ARUN T S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32369/arun-t-s/) on 2017-11-04**:
I really appreciate your help But am Getting one more error when i increased loop condition to 200(i<200)
it's like

```
wrong checksum for topic id and msg
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
That sounds like a different problem. Please use questions for single problems only.